# Bash - Syntax for multiplication of variable and function output

Tags: bash

I am currently trying multiply the variable set to the integer with a result of numberOfNodes function (integer), yet I am getting nothing. I have the following function:

```
function myfunction1(){
    $(($myVariable * `myfunction2`))
}
```

I also tried the following, but with no luck:

```
$((myVariable * myfunction2))
`$myVariable * myfunction2`
$myVariable * myfunction2
```

Comment: Is it supposed to be a reccursive function ?

Comment: is your `myFunction` (the one that you are backticking) doing a `return` or an `echo` of the number of nodes? I suspect if it `echo` the result back the backticks should be fine as-is. Try echoing out just `myfunction` and see what is spitting out of that thing.

Comment: Hi, I am so sorry - I changed the name of the function to reflect what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
function myFunc()
{
    echo 5
}

x=20
y=$(myFunc)
z=$((x*y))
echo $z
```